# PHP JS - How decrypt Youtube cipher signature correctly? (Autosolve)

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, youtube

Sorry for another post on this argument, but I don't understand why this code not working.

1) Scrape video info from /get_video_info?video_id=VIDEO_ID&el=vevo&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en

2) If use_cipher_signature isset == True it's necessary to scrape info from player_id.js. After it's necessary to get url_stream_map, find signature, decode it and append to video_url (ex. http://r13---sn-nx5cvox-hpay.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?....&signature=decrypted_sig)

I have found that the last .js file is "**player-en_US-vflkqCvzc/base.js**" with Cipher Algo

```
 var kt={
         DU:function(a){a.reverse()},
         ex:function(a,b){var c=a[0];a[0]=a[b%a.length];a[b]=c},
         Qv:function(a,b){a.splice(0,b)}
     };

 lt=function(a){
     a=a.split("");
     kt.Qv(a,2);
     kt.ex(a,6);
     kt.DU(a,64);  
     kt.Qv(a,3);
     kt.ex(a,53);
     kt.DU(a,58);
     kt.ex(a,46);
     kt.ex(a,56);
     return a.join("")
 };
```

But when I use Algo for decrypt cipher and append to playback YouTube url, not work

```
ORIGINAL
AE58CF186D2072E73B0EAC1D1A99D7F34CC772CA.897052860BD23A909A9597C0FCD3FED4F53E870C7

DECRYPTED
A8CF185D2072E73B0EAC1D1799D7F34CC772CA.897052860BD23A90969597C0FCD3FED4F53E8A (Not work!!)
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

## Solution

Hi all =) I had found a solution for this issue. It's necessary to append parameter "**sts**" to get_video_info and then perform the same operations

If You need a guide, please contact me

Comment: I just really need your help in this case so please help me. When i'm running this code on localhost it's working perfectly without Cipher issue but when i'm deploying it to server the problem is encountering with Cipher

Comment: Your account reputation here isn't good so i'm not sure you can reply on my comment or not if not then please send me a hi to mahbub.meh@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry but I was busy. If you need help please write on this post

Comment: @CodeCooker see above